# If $5 \cos^{-1}(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})+7 \sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2});\; -4 \tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})-\tan^{-1}x=5 \pi,$ then what is $x?$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$5 \cos^{-1}(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})+7 \sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})\\ -4 \tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})-\tan^{-1}x=5 \pi,$$ then what is $x?$

Attempt: let $x = \cot t = \frac{\cos t }{\sin t};$ then $$\frac{x^2 - 1}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t - 1}{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t + 1}=\cos(2t),\\
 \frac{2x}{x^2 - 1} = \frac{2\cos t/\sin t }{\cos^2 t/\sin^2 t - 1} = \tan 2t$$

now we have $$\begin{align}2\pi/3 &= \cos^{-1}(\cos(2t)) + \tan^{-1}(\tan 2t)\\
&= (2t + 2k\pi) + (2t + m\pi)  \\&= (2t) + (2t), (2t) + (2t-\pi)\\
&=4t, 4t-\pi, \cdots \end{align}$$

Comment: It is not always true that $\cos^{-1}(\cos(x))=x+2k\pi.$ It is possible that $$\cos^{-1}(\cos (x))=-x+2k\pi.$$

Comment: What is the question? Have you tried simply putting the first few of your solutions back into the original equation? Just use any calculator. If it agrees to a reasonable number of digits, you probably did everything right.

Comment: Also, by fixing $t\in(0,\pi)$ you can restrict your $k.$ $$\cos^{-1}(\cos 2t)=2t\text{ or }2\pi-2t.$$

Comment: Note in your work, you’ve reversed the signs. It was $$\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$$ and you evaluated $$\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}.$$ This is why your $\cot t$ substitution appears to work, when, in fact, $x=\tan t=\frac1{\cot t}$ is the better substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so $$5\cos^{-1}(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2})+7\sin^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})-4\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x}{1-x^2})-\tan^{-1}x=5\pi.$$

let us assume $x=\tan t$ for $t\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$
Proceeding further we will have four intervals where x can be evaluated as there is four intervals for t to be calculated $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}),[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}),[-\frac{\pi}{4},0),(-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4})$ as in the expression putting $x=\tan t$ gives us terms like $\sin^{-1}(\sin 2t)$ where actually $2t\in(-\pi,\pi)$

On calculating and checking the interval where t is belonging only $2$ interval can give us correct answer.
Intervals are $(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4}).$

For $(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$
$$10t+7(\pi-2t)-4(2t-\pi)-t=5\pi$$
$$t=\frac{6\pi}{13}$$
For $(-\frac{\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4})$
$$-10t+7(-\pi-2t)-4(2t+\pi)-t=5\pi$$
$$t=-\frac{16}{33}$$

Leading to two values of $x$ i.e. $x=\tan(\frac{6\pi}{13})=8.235740$ and $x=-\tan(\frac{16\pi}{33})=-20.9925834$

Comment: Please don't use so much vertical space.

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong. If $t>\pi/4,$ then $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2t))=\pi-2t.$ Also, if $-\pi/2\leq t<0,$ then $\cos^{-1}(cos(2t))=2t+2\pi.$ You have to take into account that $\sin^{-1},\cos^{-1},\tan^{-1}$ are not inverse functions on the entire domain of $\sin,\cos,\tan.$

Comment: Why did you take it  x=tan t?

Comment: i think now there is no problem in the domain

Comment: @Behemooth sorry now i have made it correct

Comment: You beat me to the punch. This time. +1.

Comment: You beat me to the punch is an expression, it means I was going to do what you did first.

Comment: yup i didnt knew the expression....

Comment: No, it is still wrong.

Comment: If $x=\sqrt3,$ then the expression becomes $$5\cos^{-1}(-1/2)+7\sin^{-1}(\sqrt3/2)-4\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt3)-\tan^{-1}(\sqrt3)=\\5(2\pi/3)+7(\pi/3)-4(-\pi/3)-\pi/3=20\pi/3\neq 5\pi.$$

Comment: @Behemooth this answer is wrong. You can just plug $\sqrt3$ into your original equation and check.

Comment: You’ve hidden your error by your edit, but you are still assuming $\sin^{-1}(\sin(2t))=2t.$ Hiding an error doesn’t make it not an error. This is only true for some $t,$ and in particular, not true for $t=\pi/3.$

Answer (score 1):

If $x=\tan(t)$ for $t\in \left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right),$ this becomes

$$5\cos^{-1}(\cos2t)+7\sin^{-1}(\sin2t)\\-4\tan^{-1}(\tan2t)-\tan^{-1}(\tan t)=5\pi.$$

$\tan^{-1}(\tan(t))=t$ on this entire interval. But we don’t get nice values for the other terms.

$$
\begin{align} 
\sin^{-1}(\sin(2t))&=\begin{cases}2t&|t|\leq\pi/4\\\pi-2t&t\in(\pi/4,\pi/2]\\-\pi-2t&t\in[-\pi/2,-\pi/4)\end{cases}\\\\\cos^{-1}(\cos(2t))&=\begin{cases}2t&t\in[0,\pi/2]\\-2t&t\in[-\pi/2,0)\end{cases}\\\\\tan^{-1}(\tan(2t))&=\begin{cases}2t&|t|<\frac\pi4\\2t-\pi&t\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)\\2t+\pi&t\in(-\pi/2,-\pi/4)\end{cases}
\end{align} 
$$

So you get four different intervals.

You get:

$$10t+14t-8t-t=5\pi\quad{t\in[0,\pi/4]}\\t=\pi/3,$$
but $\pi/3\notin[0,\pi/4],$ so this solution is invalid.

$$10t+7(\pi-2t)-4(2t-\pi)-t=5\pi\quad t\in(\pi/4,\pi/2)\\t=\frac{6\pi}{13}$$
which is a valid $t.$

$$-10t+14t-8t-t=5\pi\quad t\in(-\pi/4,0)\\t=-\pi
$$ but $-\pi$ is not in this interval.

$$-10t+7(-\pi-2t)-4(2t+\pi)-t=5\pi\quad t\in(-\pi/2,-\pi/4)\\t=-\frac{16}{33}\pi$$
which is in the interval.

So you get $x=\tan\frac{6\pi}{13}\approx 8.2357$ and $x=-\tan\frac{16\pi}{33}\approx-20.9926$ are your two solutions.